# NMAP not reporting open ports with -sS scan

Tags: network-scanners, ports, nmap

Is there any reason why an -sS scan (or most others) would not report an open port that doesn't have a service attached to it?

For example, in a regular -sS scan, the following port will be missing, but when I scan that port specifically, it appears as open.

PORT     STATE SERVICE

2509/tcp open  unknown

Answer (score 6):

Most likely, it's because port 2509 isn't in the 1000 most frequently used TCP ports.  Unless you specify specific ports or a port ratio or top port number, nmap scans only the 1000 most commonly seen ports.  See the [nmap user guide](http://nmap.org/book/man-port-specification.html) for details on port selection.

Comment: Thanks, went back and tried a full port scan and it was successful. Previously had used -p"*" which was wrong syntax. Worked with -p-